# libpng error: Read Error / Why can't this image be processed by OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error, png, libpng

Why can't **this specific** `test.png` image be processed by OpenCV?
Note: I posted a workaround, but I am still interested in **what the actual cause of the error is.**

```py
import cv2
cv2.imread('test.png')
```

results in
`libpng error: Read Error`, while other `.png`s get processed without error.

### Context

`cv2.version.opencv_version == '4.5.5.62'` installed via `pipenv install opencv-python` on `python 3.8`

### Test image

([image: test.png])

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that version of `libpng` is `15.13.0` according to the file name of
`lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/libpng15-ce838cd1.so.15.13.0`

Apparently, it's a bug in an older version of `libpng`, as `PIL/pillow` using `libpng16` (`Pillow.libs/libpng16-213e245f.so.16.37.0`) works just fine.

```py
# instead of:
# image = cv2.imread(img_name)

# use:
image = Image.open(img_name)

# Convert Image to numpy array
# It's not the most efficient way, but it works. *(link¹)
image = np.asarray(image)

# Remove alpha channel if existent
if len(image.shape) == 3 and image.shape[2] == 4:
    image = image[:, :, : 3]

# Restore RGB colors
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

**References:**

Performance: https://uploadcare.com/blog/fast-import-of-pillow-images-to-numpy-opencv-arrays/